# React - correct syntax to use a prop with a prefix as an ID for an element?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, react-props

What's the correct syntax to use a prop for an element id except but with a prefix. Do I have to assign each to a variable and use a string literal, or can I do it inline?

e.g.

```
<input id="first_{id}" type="text" value={firstName} />
<input id="last_{id}" type="text" value={lastName} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${}` outside your value, which is called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in javascript

```
{`your-prefix-${yourValue}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a string interpolation syntax like so

```js
<input id={`first_${id}`} type="text" value={firstName} />
```